# Sass CSS Gradient Generator

Tags: css, sass

Take a look at this JSFiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/wLkLE/2/

Trying to recreate this look http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/EyxHE/3/ with SASS so that it can easily be modified.

This is the code that I'm having trouble with...

```
@for $i from 1 through $numberOfUnits {
  if $i == 1 {
    $lineargradient: $majorColor 0%, $majorColor $majorWidthPercent, $gapColor $majorWidthPercent, $gapColor $unitWidthPercent
  }
  else if $i > 1 {
    $minor-begin: ($i-1)*$unitWidthPercent;
    $minor-end: (($i-1)*$unitWidthPercent)+$minorWidthPercent;
    $gap-begin: $minor-end;
    $gap-end: $i*$unitWidthPercent;

    $lineargradient: #{$lineargradient}, $minorColor $minor-begin, $minorColor $minor-end, $gapColor $gap-begin, $gapColor $gap-end;
  }
}​
```

I'm not sure how to code this to make it output:

```
$lineargradient: rgba(0,0,0,0.15)...
```

The [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) isn't very clear on how to do something like this

Again you can see this in JSFiddle form here:

> > http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/wLkLE/2/

Comment: I would reccomend against sass for now. Just my 2€

Comment: @ColeJohnson - why do you recommend against SASS?

Comment: It's not that I don't like it. Its that it's not popular with browsers yet. I currently just use php scripts with variables

Comment: SASS doesn't need to be supported by the browser its converted to CSS server side. That's why its called a pre-processor..

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Thanks. I was actually just wondering what you thoughts are as I'm thinking about using such pre-processors but can't be bothered as of yet. Although, like James points out, it is a pre-processor, so browsers don't need to support it.